# node-schedule job does not working in function

Tags: node.js, for-loop, nodemailer

I am trying to work with node-schedule. I want to create a dynamic scheduler. I want to set rule for schedule dynamically. Its working fine when it is called as per the documentation on github. But when I take it in a function through loop then its not working. My code is given below. In code smtp email address has been modified for security purpose.

```
con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {
           var dt = dateTime.create(result[i].expire_date);
           var formattedDate = dt.format('Y-m-d');
           if (result[i].payment_status === 0) {
               var dt_str = formattedDate.split('-');
               var dt_year = parseInt(dt_str[0]);
               var dt_month = parseInt(dt_str[1]);
               var dt_date = parseInt(dt_str[2]);

               var mail_to = result[i].email, mail_sub='Schedule Of Maintenance', mail_message='Test Mail message Status';
               console.log('ScheduleCron Function calling');

               scheduleCron(dt_date,dt_month, dt_year, mail_to, mail_sub, mail_message);
           } else {
               console.log(result[i].payment_status);
           }
        }
    });
});

function scheduleCron(schedule_date,schedule_month,schedule_year,mail_to,mail_sub,mail_message) {

console.log(schedule_date+'  '+schedule_month+'  '+schedule_year);
console.log('ScheduleCron Function In');

var date = new Date(schedule_year, schedule_month, schedule_date, 13, 33, 0);
schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
    sendEmail( mail_to, mail_sub, mail_message);
    });
}


function sendEmail(mail_to,mail_sub,mail_message) {
   var mailOptions = {
      from: "email@gmail.com",
      to: mail_to,
      subject: mail_sub,
      text: mail_message

   };
   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
       if (error) {
        throw error;
       } else {
        console.log("Email successfully sent!");
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a job object as you see in documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

```
const job = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
    sendEmail( mail_to, mail_sub, mail_message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Job object which is required by the scheduling algorithm.
From the documentation

**Jobs and Scheduling**

Every scheduled job in Node Schedule is represented by a Job object. You can create jobs manually, then execute the schedule() method to apply a schedule, or use the convenience function scheduleJob() as demonstrated below.

Answer (score 1):

I was confused by this too.  I couldn't understand why this wasn't working, I mean "myFunc()" is a function. right?  So you throw myFunc() into the second argument of scheduleJob():

```
function myFunc(){
    console.log("stuff");
    do.otherStuff();
}

schedule.scheduleJob('*/10 * * * *', myFunc());
```

But for some strange reason, it has to be called like this:

```
function myFunc(){
    console.log("stuff");
    do.otherStuff();
}

schedule.scheduleJob('*/10 * * * *', function(){
    myFunc();
});
```

to avoid the `TypeError: this.job.execute is not a function` error when it executes.

Comment: Thank you for providing one of those special answers that makes a fellow feel validated!